# Template container of type T and its pointer type

Tags: c++, templates

Searching around for iterator implementation examples for template containers in C++ has gotten me confused. This is probably due to my lack of template-fu. I've seen the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct iterator_traits
{
    typedef T           value_type;
    typedef T&          reference_type;
    typedef T*          iterator;
    typedef const T*    const_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
};

template<typename T>
struct iterator_traits<T*>
{
    typedef T*          value_type;
    typedef T*&         reference_type;
    typedef T**         iterator;
    typedef const T     const_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator> reverse_iterator;
};
```

What I am confused about is the T vs T*. Both structs are templated with typename T but one of them is specialized with T*. Does this mean the compiler will try to match T* (pointers of type T) to the second iterator_traits instead of the first one? If I don't have such template specialization declared, why can't I expect the compiler to replace T with T* using the first template declaration?

Comment: `const_iterator` is broken in the pointer specialization.

Comment: That's not how `iterator_traits` is supposed to be defined...

Comment: The point of the question isn't about iterator_traits .. but the <T*>. I simply copied this from another post and wanted to ask about the T*. Thanks for confirming it tho.

Comment: "why can't I expect the compiler to replace T with T* using the first template declaration?" because T *will be* some `type*`

Comment: The search term you are looking for is [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)

Comment: Thank you @IgorTandetnik! Is there any reason we need such partial specialization?

Comment: Try to implement an equivalent of [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) without. That may prove illuminating.